# Printg problem at flowDocument's inner checkbox

Tags: wpf, printing, checkbox, flowdocument

I wonder whether this is right way to print flowdocument :( 
but this is a very strange phenomenon.

My Code like this:

```
string flowDocString =
" <FlowDocument xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation'>" +
"      <Section>" +
"          <Paragraph>" +
"              <CheckBox IsChecked='True'>Test</CheckBox>" +
"          </Paragraph>" +
"      </Section>" +
" </FlowDocument>";
FlowDocument flowDoc = (FlowDocument)XamlReader.Load(new MemoryStream(new UTF8Encoding().GetBytes(flowDocString)));

PrintDialog printDlg = new PrintDialog();
IDocumentPaginatorSource idpSource = flowDoc;
printDlg.PrintDocument(idpSource.DocumentPaginator, "Hello WPF Printing.");
```

When I use this code, the checkbox's state is still unchecked.
But when I modify the flowDocString like this:

```
string flowDocString =
" <FlowDocument xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation'>" +
"      <Section>" +
"          <Paragraph>" +
"              <CheckBox IsChecked='True' IsEnabled='False'>Test</CheckBox>" +
"          </Paragraph>" +
"      </Section>" +
" </FlowDocument>";
```

If you modify the above results will be displayed as intended.
How can this happened? Please tell me why.